# Derivative including kronecker product

Tags: matrix-calculus, chain-rule, kronecker-product

Suppose that $\delta$ is a $p\times1$ vector and $M$ is a symmetric $Np\times Np$ matrix.

I'm trying to differentiate $\ln L=\ln|(I_{N}\otimes\delta')M(I_{N}\otimes\delta)|$ with respect to $\delta$ , where $|A|$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$.

I know that $\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial(I_{N}\otimes\delta)}=2M(I_{N}\otimes\delta)[(I_{N}\otimes\delta')M(I_{N}\otimes\delta)]^{-1}$ given that $M$ is symmetric.

How should I apply the chain rule to get $\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \delta}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the following variables
$$x=\delta,\qquad Y=I_N\otimes x,\qquad A = Y^TMY,\qquad\lambda=\ln(\det(A))$$
Assume you are given an *analytic* function of a scalar variable and its derivative
$$f=f(s),\qquad p(s)=\frac{df}{ds}$$
These functions can be applied to a square matrix argument
to yield the matrix values
$$F=f(A),\qquad P=p(A)$$
The gradient (or equivalently the differential)
of the trace of the matrix function can be written as
$$\frac{\partial {\rm Tr}(F)}{\partial A} = P^T 
  \quad\iff\quad d\,{\rm Tr}(F) = P^T:dA$$
In this particular case, the scalar functions that will be needed are
$$f(s)=\ln(s),\qquad p(s)=s^{-1}$$
and the matrices are symmetric.

Therefore
$$\eqalign{
d\lambda &= d\,\ln(\det(A)) \\
 &= d\,{\rm Tr}(\ln(A))
 &\quad\big({\rm Jacobi\,formula}\big) \\
 &= A^{-1}:dA \\
 &= A^{-1}:(Y^TM\,dY+dY^TMY) \\
 &= 2A^{-1}:Y^TM\,dY \\
 &= 2MYA^{-1}:dY \\
 &= 2MYA^{-1}:(I_N\otimes dx)
 &\quad\big({\rm Your\,formula}\big) \\
 &= 2\;{\rm vec}\big(MYA^{-1}\big):\big({\rm vec}(I_N)\otimes I_p\big)\,dx\\
 &= 2\,\big({\rm vec}(I_N)\otimes I_p\big)^T{\rm vec}\big(MYA^{-1}\big):dx\\
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial x}
 &= 2\,\big({\rm vec}(I_N)\otimes I_p\big)^T{\rm vec}\big(MYA^{-1}\big) \\
}$$

---

In several of the steps above, a colon is used to denote
the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A 
}$$